# XY Scatter Plot and Dictionary problems

Tags: vba, excel, office-2010

I have a function to generate XY scatter plots based on any number of dictionaries (with each dictionary representing a line on the graph), each containing a date key and a number value. So far the values seem to work on the Y axis, but the date axis (X) seems to be broken. Every time I add the series to the graph from the dictionary, it forces it to a bar graph, when I specifically want a scatter plot. If I force it back to a scatter plot after assigning it, it completely refuses to display the date axis at all.

Here are some examples.

I want the graph to look like this
[image]

If I tell it not to use a date, the graph looks like this

[image]

When I specifically set the data type of the series to xlDate, the graph changes to this. It has mysteriously changed to a bar graph

[image]

if I specifically change it back to a scatter plot after setting it to use an xlDate, it looks like this

[image]

Any help would be very much appreciated. Here is my VBA code

```
Sub GenerateProgressGraph()


Dim Dictionaries(1 To 2) As New Dictionary

    Dictionaries(1).Add DateValue("1/2/2012"), 1
    Dictionaries(1).Add DateValue("2/2/2012"), 2
    Dictionaries(1).Add DateValue("3/2/2012"), 3
    Dictionaries(1).Add DateValue("4/2/2012"), 4

    Dictionaries(2).Add DateValue("1/2/2012"), 1
    Dictionaries(2).Add DateValue("2/2/2012"), 1
    Dictionaries(2).Add DateValue("3/2/2012"), 3
    Dictionaries(2).Add DateValue("4/2/2012"), 4

    Call ProcessProgressGraph(Dictionaries)
End Sub

Sub ProcessProgressGraph(Dict() As Dictionary)

    Dim Graph As Shape
    Dim GraphRange As Range

    With ActiveSheet

        'set graph area
        Set GraphRange = Application.Range("E4:P21")

        'add a new chart
        Set Graph = Shapes.AddChart(xlXYScatterLinesNoMarkers, GraphRange.Left, _
                                    GraphRange.Top, GraphRange.Width, GraphRange.Height)

        With Graph.Chart

            With .Axes(xlCategory)
                .HasTitle = True
                .AxisTitle.Characters.Text = "Dates"
            End With

            .HasTitle = True
            .ChartTitle.Text = "Chart Title"
            .ChartType = xlXYScatterLinesNoMarkers

            'clear all chart data
            '(Excel has a tendency to give us silly resultsets by default)
            For Each srs In .SeriesCollection
                srs.Delete
            Next

            For Each Dictionary In Dict
                Dim ss As Series
                Set ss = .SeriesCollection.NewSeries
                ss.Name = "Values"
                ss.XValues = Dictionary.Keys
                ss.Type = xlDate
                .ChartType = xlXYScatterLinesNoMarkers 'this forces it back into a scatter plot since it auto makes a bar graph
                ss.Values = Dictionary.Items
            Next
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: The problem is that your dates are coming in as labels rather than as Excel date values ("1/2/2012" rather than 40910, for example).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem lies in Excel's native handling of the X axis values. to be honest, i have no idea why this happens, but i know how to solve it:

1. Get your X axis date values and cast them to type Long using something like this:

   ```
   ReDim longDates(Dictionary.Count) as Long
   For i = LBound(Dictionary.Keys) to UBound(Dictionary.Keys)
       longDates(i) = Dictionary.Keys(i)
   Next
   ```
2. Assign the longDates to be the X axis values using `ss.XValues = longDates`
3. Set the TickLabel number format to date at the **end** of the function using:

   ```
   .Axes(xlCategory).TickLabels.NumberFormat = "d/mm/yyyy"
   ```

That should work